# What is the best way to make sure I can always submerge myself as a locathah?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits

I want to make a locathah, but don't want to die by being away from water. Without being forced into some specific class, is there any way to ensure I can always find water with some skill or something?

Here is the relevant racial trait from [Locathah Rising](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/digital-only-rpg-products/locathah-rising):

> **Limited Amphibiousness.** You can breathe air and water, but you need to be submerged at least once every 4 hours to avoid suffocating.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! You might want to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance.

Answer (score 21):

## Get a buy-in from your Dungeon Master

What you are trying to do, is to play a race with all its strength, but avoid its drawback instead of embracing it. That is indeed a common approach¹, and I dare a guess that's why 5e got rid of negative racial modifiers to stats, as they were used with classes for which they didn't matter anyway.

If your DM will decide that getting wet is important to balance out the goodies you got, like water breathing, skill proficiencies, save advantages etc, no matter what game mechanics you will try to use, you will have no guarantees and any DM worth his salt will find ways to make the risk real for you. It will be a problem for you to solve in-game, and you will need to change solutions once in a while. So only way to make sure it won't happen, is to have a deal with DM during session 0.

**By the way**, if your DM will agree to it, other players may be jaded that you got some goodies for free and they didn't. On the other hand, if risk of drying out will be real for you, it will inconvenience the whole party, not just you. So either way, before playing this race it is a good idea to talk to the fellow players and make sure they are comfortable with whatever solution you and your DM are ready to agree on.

---

¹ Observation from my experience and from looking at questions on this site.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135482/discussion-on-answer-by-molot-what-is-the-best-way-to-make-sure-i-can-always-sub).

Comment: While this input is worthwhile for many players trying characters of unusual races, it should probably be changed to a comment. This does not give an answer to the question. It is just some solid feedback on the player's decisions with their character.

Comment: @LoganKitchen I answered the question as asked. Sure, it may not be what OP hoped to get, but he asked how to be sure and I described the only 100% reliable method.

Answer (score 15):

The most reliable and accessible way is the first-level spell Create or Destroy Water, which is available to clerics, druids, certain paladin and warlock subclasses, as well as any character by taking the magic initiate feat.  The spell produces 10 gallons of water per cast, which is arguably enough to submerge, depending on what sort of container you have to hand.

For "best" options, you'll want to look to magic items - the Decanter of Endless Water is an uncommon magic item that can produce, well, endless amounts of water for free, so it's probably the best choice.  A bag of holding is also uncommon and can hold 500 pounds of water, which should be plenty, and the space inside the bag is already a container within which one could be submerged, which is potentially an upside if you're worried about needing to submerge yourself on a perfectly flat plane or the top of a tree or something.

Comment: I don't think 10 gallons would be enough.  A basic bathtub bath takes around 30 gallons of water and that's just barely enough to get your whole body under.

Comment: A cubic foot is 27 liters of water, so call it 7 gallons. 10 gallons is less than 1.5 cubic feet.

Comment: @JonCuster Indeed. And despite this I always get funny looks for picking up _Purify Food and Drink_ (which can theoretically process just over _3900 gallons_ of water in a single cast) instead of _Create and Destroy Water_ in seafaring campaigns...